# Is there a way to say that two adjacent CSS grid columns take a certain amount of space in sum?

Tags: css, grid-layout

I have a CSS grid layout with four columns and I need the first two and the second two to take 50% of the container width each. But I don't know the width of the odd columns.

So basically something like `grid-template-columns: auto calc(50% - auto) auto calc(50% - auto);` I know this doesn't work but I was wondering if this is possible at all. Has anyone ever been in a similar situation and have any suggestions?

edit: so the green columns should fit to the content and the blue ones take the remaining space. The red line is at 50% of the container width.

[image: graphical explanation]

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto 1fr;
  width:  300px;
}

.container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.fit {
  background-color: lime;
}

.container > div:not(.fit) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#helper1 {
    grid-column: 1/3;
    background-color: orange;
}

#helper2 {
    grid-column: 3/5;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fit">ABC</div>
  <div>0</div>
  <div class="fit">A</div>
  <div>1<br>2<br>3</div>
  <div class="fit">A</div>
  <div>4<br>5</div>
  <div class="fit">ABCDEFG</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div class="fit">B</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div class="fit">D</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div id="helper1">50%</div>
  <div id="helper2">50%</div>
</div>
```

So, what values to use for grid-template-columns, so that the blue colums don't have equal width but sum up with their left adjacent to 50% of the container's width.

Comment: you cannot nest them in the same container?

Comment: they are in one container. I can't seperate them because I need all rows to behave equally

Comment: share your specific code then since you have more constraint

Comment: I don't have any working code. I added a little graphic to make it more clear.

Comment: A screenshot/image is not good enough. Please, post the current code you have. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible, but what you have your hands on is a case of nesting grids. I'd recommend looking into using flexbox as an alternative for situations like these, but here's a stackblitz that may give some grid-related inspiration https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsaato?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

The reason revolves around the 'auto' sizing of columns is used to fill available space, similar to how flexbox works, but it can't be segmented within a single grid. Thus, we make like a bird and nest!

Hope it's what you're looking for, happy coding!